# Prevent self extracting application entering sandbox mode on Windows 11

Tags: c#, sandbox, windows-11, self-extracting, ionic-zip

I have a self-extracting c# winforms app (implemented by Ionic.Zip 1.9.2.0) that runs on .NET Framework 4.5. Another winforms application manages the app and exports it to a temp folder for running. After I executed the main program without administrator rights and called the console application, Windows opened it in a safe (I think) sandbox mode and created another 2 processes and a console window. It works the same way as on Windows 10 if I run with admin account. Is there a way to prevent executing as a normal user from entering sandbox mode?

I was able to run the executable without entering sandbox mode from the CLI when I copied the binaries from the temp folder, but this is not a workaround for the average user.